Отправка формы обратной связи без перезагрузки страницы
Всем добрый день! Есть форма обратной связи на Simpla CMS.
С других страниц, как известно у симплы action можно указать только адрес /contact/, т.к. обработчик во вью файле и в .htaccess указан
# feedback
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?module=FeedbackView  [L,QSA]

В таком случае форма отправляется, но страница перезагружается и появляется сообщение "Спасибо" если ты на странице контакты. Если с другой то перекидает на страницу контакты. В обеих случаях форма успешно отправляется.
Вопрос - как можно сделать чтоб с других страниц не перекидало на страницу контакты а без перезагрузки страницы просто писало спасибо. Либо с перезагрузкой но оставляло посетителя на этой же странице и выкидало сообщение спасибо.
Нид хелп.
Код самой формы:
<form action="/contact/" method="post" class="form1">
<strong>Задайте вопрос</strong>
<input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" class="scalable"><br />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Пользователь" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="нет" />
<textarea name="title" class="" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Текст" class="scalable"></textarea><br />
<button type="submit" name="feedback" value="1" class="yellow">Отправить</button>
</form>


Можно поиском воспользоваться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Если у вас вопрос по Simpla CMS, то его надо задавать на соответствующем сайте. Мы можем только дать ссылку на стандартное решение
